# My Minecraft account is taking forever to sign in

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-10

Whenever I press the sign-in option, it takes forever to load. I left it for 3 hours once and it still won't sign in. It's just stuck on the loading screen. I already tried uninstalling it, and I don't really have any other apps installed, so what should I do? I'm on the Windows 10 one if that makes anything clearer.

Comment: Hey, are you on Windows 10 Edition (Bedrock) or Java Edition? *Reason for Rollback: The question is tagged Java, and "I'm on the Windows 10 one" could easily just mean he is using Windows 10. Until it's been explicitly stated I believe it's best to assume what it already says.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you uninstalled Minecraft only on a surface level, or have you deleted all the files?
Go to your .minecraft folder in Appdata and delete all of your files there and reinstall, or, if you want to save some info, backup your saved worlds onto your computer and then delete the files and reinstall. Unclear as to if you're using Windows 10 or Java, as you've tagged your answer with Java but said you're using the "Windows 10 one". However, this should work with both versions. If this still doesn't work, try uninstalling and reinstalling Java, and then try restarting your computer. If your computer is a really old computer, it might actually be because of lag problems as well. Let me know what solution worked for you, or if nothing I wrote here is working.

Comment: I meant that I was using pc, I didn't realize that my tag said Java. I don't actually have any Minecraft folders in my AppData which I found weird. I also already tried restarting my computer after deleting Minecraft. I've had my computer for about a year, so I don't think it's considered old.

Comment: Try starting minecraft up again with a lower version, like 1.8.9 if you're using 1.16. Do you have "Hidden items" checked in your file explorer? You might want to reinstall java as well.

Answer (score 0):

Before waiting 30 minutes and seeing an error message, sign into the Xbox Console Companion application. Load up Minecraft, and you should be able to sign in.

If you can't, wait until the error message appears, press <kbd>esc</kbd> and close Minecraft properly. Alternatively, continue trying to sign in.

Never close Minecraft without pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> from the title menu. If you close it using the normal way, exceptions like these may occur. Never delete files from the AppData folders; they are very sensitive, and doing so can break Minecraft and render it useless.